# How to make embed videos responsive on mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4, responsive

I want to know how can i make my embed video is responsive on mobile view?

this is my code for desktop view, but how to make this video fit on mobile view

```
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop" class="embed-responsive-item">
            <source src="example.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
          </video>
        </div>
```

[image]

this is mobile view for the video, i want to make it fit for mobile

i hope you guys can understand what's my problem here. Thank you for answering this question

Comment: without seeing your css code we can't help you please read [mcve]

Comment: I'm sorry for that issue @Sfili_81, but i dont add anything code to my css, i just use bootstrap responsive code

Answer (score 0):

The best way i have found to make videos responsive on mobile would be to create a 16-9.gif and put that with height 100% and width 100%, then have this set in a container set to relative. Then set the video element to position absolute, left 0 ,right 0, top 0, bottom 0, height:100% and width 100%. This will then take up the entire height of the gif and then scale.

```
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"> <-- set relative
      <video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop" class="embed-responsive-item"> <-- set absolute
        <source src="example.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
      </video>
      <img src="this will be your gif of 16-9"/> <-- set height and width
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, i'll try it soon